# HipChat Nodejs Bot - Cant receive room messages

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp, hipchat

I am trying to create an hip chat bot with nodejs. The main library is node-xmpp. However at the moment the build is failing and I think thats why my nom install doesn't work.

Any who I managed to write my own version based on the core modules.
- node-xmpp-client
- node-xmpp-component
- node-xmpp-jid

I can see messages fine and send. But only private! although I am registered in a room I cannot see room messages.

The source code of node-xmpp says thats a message or stanza should have a type and from that understand if the message is private or not. Well to me only private messages come. I wonder if its an issue with Hipchat.

If you want to take a look at the code, I made a github repo as it would an overkill to page here. [github](https://github.com/drakoumel/bmo/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' lies with the xmpp protocol itself. 
Due to the way the protocol works, you need to have joined the room before you can receive messages from it. 
Why I was, lead to believe otherwise, was because hip chat showed the user as online on the room, but in reality he is not online on the group he is just online.